# prove that $\exists\ \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall x\in [0,1] : f(x)>x+\epsilon$

Tags: calculus, inequality, continuity

the question itself:

> Let $f$ be a continuous function in the close interval $[0,1]$ which upholds the rule: $\forall x\in [0,1] : f(x)>x$. prove that $\exists\ \epsilon>0$ such that $\forall x\in [0,1] : f(x)>x+\epsilon$.

**my proof (by contradiction):**

we suppose the opposite:

$\forall \ \epsilon>0 \ \exists x_0\in [0,1] : f(x_0)\le x_0+\epsilon$

so because of continuity $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\le x_0+\epsilon$

then $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)-x_0\le \epsilon$

so   $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)-\lim_{x\to x_0}x\le \epsilon$

and now $\ \lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-x)\le \epsilon$

and we get $\ \ 0\le \lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-x)\le \epsilon$

because $f(x)-x>0$ from the datum

so when $\epsilon$ approaches zero the rhs limit is zero and the lhs limit is of course, zero and thus by sandwich rule we get $\ \ \lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-x)=0$.

But because both $f(x),x$ are continuous in $[0,1]$ we get that $f(x)-x$ is also continuous and by definition we get $\lim_{x\to x_0}(f(x)-x)=f(x_0)-x_0$.

now $f(x_0)-x_0=0$ so $f(x_0)=x_0$; that's a contradiction to the datum.

please confirm me that my proof is right and if it's wrong please mention my mistake.

Comment: I'd go by the definition of limit to be more strictly correct

Comment: $g(x) = f(x) - x$ a continuous function over a closed interval.  It must have a minimum value and that value is greater than 0.  Conversely, what you are trying to prove, would not be true if the problem were defined over the open interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and  $m=\inf_{x\in[0,1]} g(x)$ then since $g$ is continuous on a compact so by Weierstrass theorem this minimum is attained  i.e. there is $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that $g(x)\ge g(x_0)=m>0$. Take $\epsilon=\frac m2$.